# Publishing Container to Quay by Example

Tags: docker, versioning

I'm trying to figure out how to publish a versioned Docker container to Quay.io and am not seeing how to do so [in their docs](https://docs.quay.io/solution/getting-started.html). From the docs:

```
# Login to Quay.io
docker login quay.io (will now be prompted for username + password)

# Get your <containerID>
docker ps -l

# Tag that container by <containerId>
docker commit <containerId> quay.io/<myUsername>/<myRegistry>

# Now publish it to Quay.io
docker push quay.io/<myUsername>/<myRegistry>
```

However this leaves me very confused:

- What if I want my containers tagged/versioned with, say, `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`, or `1.0-rc`, or `2.0` or `3.1.6-G.A`? Where do I specify the actual tag name/version?
- When I run the `docker push` command, how does Docker know which (tagged/versioned) container to publish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, it's worth noting that you don't push *containers* to a registry.  You push *images*.  The `docker commit` command in your question creates new image based on an active container.

When assigning tags to images -- using either the `docker tag` command, which is more common [1], or when using `docker commit` -- the format of a tag is `[<registry>/]<repository>[:<tag>]`, where `[...]` is used to represent an option component.  So for example you might tag an image targeting your account on Docker Hub like this:

```
docker tag smeeb/webserver
```

This would be assigned the `latest` tag, since you haven't specified one explicitly.  To explicitly assign the tag `awesome` instead of `latest`:

```
docker tag smeeb/webserver:awesome
```

When you're tagging an image for an alternate registry, you include the registry name as part of the tag, as in:

```
docker tag <imageId> quay.io/smeeb/webserver
```

Here, `quay.io` is the registry, `smeeb/webserver` is the repository, and you've implicitly assigned the `latest` tag.  You can be explicit instead:

```
docker tag <imageId> quay.io/smeeb/webserver:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

And so forth.  You can use the same syntax when creating images with `docker commit`.

[1]: The reason I saw that using `docker tag` is more common is that use of `docker commit` is generally considered an anti-pattern.  Use a `Dockerfile` to create your new image, which makes it much easier to reproduce the same configuration (and allows you to version control the configuration of your image).

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks @larsks (+1) - is it safe to assume that you can *only* do a `docker tag` **after** you do a `docker build`? I assume that's the case, since there wouldn't be anything taggable until you've built an image, right? Thanks again!

Comment: You can only tag an existing image using the `docker tag` command.  You can assign a tag as part of the `docker build` process with the `-t` argument to `docker build`.